# Google Sheet Data Connector to Bigquery Disappeared

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

Existing working connections to Bigquery from Google Sheets (using the new data connector) just stopped working yesterday, and now do not show up in the "Data" menu as before.

Anyone else experiencing?  And, knows how to mitigate?

Support suggested trying to make a new sheet in incognito mode, but it still is just missing from the menu now:

[image: Not showing up in menu.]

It appears the exiting sheets just don't have "Refresh" as an option anymore, despite remaining in the sheet:

[image: Refresh option missing]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are right. It was available for "Business", but now it is restricted to Entreprise+.

Below the response I got from Sheets Team.

> Thanks for contacting Google Cloud Support, my name is XXXXXXXX and I
> am with the Sheets Specialist Team. (...). I see that you have lost
> access to Bigquery in Sheets. I regret to inform you that the feature
> is no longer available for G Suite Business accounts, you would need
> to upgrade to G Suite Enterprise for the feature to be available
> again, you will find additional information in this Help Center
> article: https://support.google.com/a/answer/9604541. Please let me
> know if this answers your question or if additional support is
> required.

Best Regards.
Gabriel

Comment: Very frustrating

Answer (score 1):

It appears Google has released a big update to the Data Connector for bigquery, which actually adds a lot of functionality (including pivots, calculated columns within the sheet, and a refresh schedule).

However, they have now limited which types of accounts can use the connector:
[image]

See https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9077536?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

And, this list (at least as of 7/18/2020) no longer includes "Business" tier -- which is disappointing to say the least.